# Was I wrong to omit angles in the solution set for this multiple angle problem?

Tags: trigonometry

I may have missed this in my precalculus course, but why was I wrong to omit angles that did not have a positive value for cosine? I didn't include $\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{12},\frac{5\pi}{4}$ because I thought they would not equal positive $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. Here is a screenshot of my missed question. Thanks in advance!

[image: Screenshot of MyMathLab question]

Comment: $\cos(x)$ is indeed not positive $\sqrt{2}/2$ at $x = 3\pi/4$, $x = 7\pi/12$, and $x = 5\pi/4$. However, the question is not about $\cos(x)$, it's about $\cos(3x)$. Tripling the size of the angle before taking the cosine affects the value (here, specifically, the sign) of the resulting cosine. And, lo and behold, $$\cos\left(3\cdot\frac{3\pi}{4}\right) = \cos\left(3\cdot\frac{7\pi}{12}\right) = \cos\left(3\cdot\frac{5\pi}{4}\right) = +\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be surer of not missing solutions by approaching the equation something like this.  Designate the angle as $ \ \alpha \ = \ 3 \ x \ $ and solve the equation as

$$ \cos \alpha \ = \ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \alpha \ = \ \frac{\pi}{4} \ + \ 2 \ k \ \pi \ , \ \frac{7\pi}{4} \ + \ 2 \ k \ \pi \ \ . $$

We then have

$$ 3x \ = \ \frac{\pi}{4} \ + \ 2 \ k \ \pi \ , \ \frac{7\pi}{4} \ + \ 2 \ k \ \pi  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ \frac{\pi}{12} \ + \ \frac{2}{3}  k \ \pi \ , \ \frac{7\pi}{12} \ + \ \frac{2}{3}   k \ \pi $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ k \ = \ 0 \ : \ \  x \ = \ \frac{\pi}{12} \ , \ \frac{7 \pi}{12} \ \ ;  $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ k \ = \ 1 \ : \ \  x \ = \ \frac{\pi}{12} \ + \ \frac{2 \cdot 1 \cdot \pi}{3} \ = \ \frac{9 \pi}{12} \ = \ \frac{3 \pi}{4} \ \ , $$
$$ \frac{7 \pi}{12} \ + \ \frac{2 \cdot 1 \cdot \pi}{3} \ = \ \frac{15 \pi}{12} \ = \ \frac{5 \pi}{4} \ \ ;  $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ k \ = \ 2 \ : \ \  x \ = \ \frac{\pi}{12} \ + \ \frac{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \pi}{3} \ = \ \frac{17 \pi}{12}  \ \ , \ \ \frac{7 \pi}{12} \ + \ \frac{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \pi}{3} \ = \ \frac{23 \pi}{12} \ \ .  $$

You can stop at this point, since $ \ k = 3 \ $ will just add $ \ 2 \pi \ $ to your basic solutions; you have now covered the "principal circle" completely.  A general "rule of thumb" is that a trigonometric equation with a multiple angle $ \ kx \ $ , such as $ \ \sin (kx) \ = \ C \ $ , has $ \ k \ $ times as many solutions in the principal circle as $ \ \sin x \ = \ C \ $ does (since the multiplier reduces the period of the trig function by a factor of $ \ k \ $ ) .

Answer (score 0):

Well $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ is a solution in the sense they intended since it clearly is in $[0,2\pi)$ and $\cos(\frac{9\pi}{4}) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Having said that I would just like to say I really dislike "problems" like this "homework question" whose sole purpose seems to be for people to make mistakes like this.

Comment: I agree, and I probably should have labeled it an exercise at that. I guess I'm missing why that is a solution on the given interval. I'd say it's something simple, but I've been studying for a test and my brain is a little cloudy. Shouldn't solutions only be those angles which give a positive value in this case? I mean, wouldn't $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ be $\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}$?

Comment: In the original equation, using $ \ x = \frac{3 \pi}{4} \ $ gives $ \ \cos (\frac{9 \pi}{4}) \ = \  \cos (\frac{ \pi}{4}) \ = \ +\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \ $ .

Comment: @Timotej It is easy to make mistakes with such trig equations if the reason for the multiplication of the number of solutions in the principal circle is not explained.  In this problem, $ \ \cos \ 3x \ $ has a period of $ \ \frac{2 \pi}{3} \ $ , so we should expect $ \ 3 \cdot 2 = 6 \ $ solutions for the equation in the principal circle.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, I ran to my computer to post that I had realized I wasn't accounting for the period of $cos {3x}$ and then I saw your answer. I can't add anything to my original post, but I would like to say thank you very, very much for taking the time to explain this to me in such a way that I will remember it on test day. People like you make this site a great resource for students like me without quick access to a math lab.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words.  That is the way I teach the solution of "multiple-angle" trig equations because it makes the mechanics of solving them fairly straightforward.  You will also run into this again when you get to DeMoivre's Theorem and the roots of complex numbers.